# Min Max Scaler on parts of data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe like this:

```
### To Stack

df_stack = pd.DataFrame([['SGA', 'FT', 5.6994352340698242],
   ['SGA', 'ST', 1.518241786956787],
   ['EXT', 'FT', 20.853669309616087],
   ['EXT', 'ST', 3.5596847057342529],
   ['LGT', 'FT', 9.853669309616087],
   ['LGT', 'ST', 8.5596847057342529]], columns = (('idobj','description','value')))

df_stack

    idobj   description value
    SGA FT         5.69944
    SGA ST         1.51824
    EXT FT        20.85367
    EXT ST         3.55968
    LGT FT         9.85367
    LGT ST         8.5596
```

I need to apply min-max scaling on parts of data (e.g., apply `MinMaxScaler` on `'Description'='ST'`, then apply `MinMaxScaler` on `'Description'='ST'`).

When I apply `MinMaxScaler` for each "Description" this way:

```
scaler.fit(df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value'].values.reshape(-1,1))
scaler.transform(df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value'].values.reshape(-1,1))

array([[0.     ],
       [1.     ],
       [0.27413]])

scaler.fit(df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='ST')]['value'].values.reshape(-1,1))
scaler.transform(df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='ST')]['value'].values.reshape(-1,1))

array([[0.     ],
       [0.28992],
       [1.     ]])
```

I end up losing the correspondence with my "Description".

I've tried to manually compute by adding a new column like this:

```
df_stack['description_norm'] = (df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value']-\
                              df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value'].min())/\
                            (df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value'].max()-\
                             df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value'].min())
```

But then I get another column:

```
idobj   description value   description_norm
0   SGA FT  5.69944        0.00000
1   SGA ST  1.51824        NaN
2   EXT FT  20.85367       1.00000
3   EXT ST  3.55968        NaN
4   LGT FT  9.85367        0.27413
5   LGT ST  8.55968        NaN
```

And when I try to assign the values on this new column to the variable 'Description' based on the condition 'FT' it simply doesn't work?!?

```
df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['value']=df_stack[(df_stack['description']=='FT')]['description_norm']
```

What am I missing?

The expected result should be :

```
    idobj   description value
    SGA FT         0
    SGA ST         0
    EXT FT         1
    EXT ST         0.28992
    LGT FT         0.27413
    LGT ST         1
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is applying a function on a column based on the value of another column, in pandas the best way to do this is by using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

In this case, we can do the scaling manually like this:

```
df_stack['value'] = df_stack.groupby('description')['value'].\
    apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))
```

or by using [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

```
df_stack['value'] = df_stack.groupby('description')['value'].\
    transform(lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1)).flatten())
```

Both will give the same result:

```
  idobj description     value
0   SGA          FT  0.000000
1   SGA          ST  0.000000
2   EXT          FT  1.000000
3   EXT          ST  0.289918
4   LGT          FT  0.274130
5   LGT          ST  1.000000
```